# Umbraco 4.11 MVC Mode - Children Url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

What is the correct way to obtain the URLs of children of the current node while using Umbraco 4.11 in MVC mode? This is what I tried and it keeps returning a blank URL:

```
@if (CurrentPage.Children().Count() > 0) {
    <ul>
    @foreach (var child in CurrentPage.Children()) {
        <li><a href="@child.Url">@child.Name</a></li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

When that didn't work I resorted to the following:

```
@Umbraco.NiceUrl(child.Id)
```

This returns a URL, but it has .aspx extension on it. So my next hack is...

```
@Umbraco.NiceUrl(child.Id).Replace(".aspx", "")
```

That's not completely terrible, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the NiceUrl() method to generate a valid Url.
To get rid of the .aspx extension, you need to set the setting "umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" to true in your web.config file:

```
<add key="umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" value="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do it without the trailing slash?

Comment: It comes default with the trailing slash. I don't think there is a config setting to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

I can't add this as a comment, but there is a way to remove trailing slashes, in umbracoSettings.config:

```
<addTrailingSlash>true</addTrailingSlash>
```

Comment: Missed that one. Thanks, worked like a charm. No clue why these settings are scattered between web.config and umbracoSettings.config!?!

Comment: Now that I have the conventions worked out, I just need a better idea for a site worth building :) Might need to sign up for Umbraco.tv to figure out how to best structure my sites, but not sure how much of it actually applies to the current version.

Comment: Most of it should apply to the current version, depending on the videos you are looking at. It's only the underlying layers that have changed recently (for example with MVC support being introduced, and the API undergoing an overhaul), but breaking changes happen rarely and are usually documented.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to get Only Node Name (Without .aspx) is

```
@Model.NodeById(@child.Id).urlName
```

But it will just give Node name without "/"